# Sorting by absolute value for value different of zero for one column keeping equal value of another column together

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sorting

I have the following dataframe :

```
A    B    C   
============
11   x    2 
11   y    0
13   x  -10 
13   y    0
10   x    7
10   y    0
```

and i would like to sort C by absolute value for value different of 0. But as i need to keep A values together it would look like below (sorted by absolute value but with 0 in between):

```
A    B    C   
============
13   x  -10 
13   y    0
10   x    7 
10   y    0
11   x    2
11   y    0
```

I can't manage to obtain this with `sort_values()`. If i sort by C, i don't have A values together.

Comment: I just want to be clear here. You want to keep the value of C. IOW sort by abs(C) not take the abs of C and then sort it.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: get absolute values

```
# creating a column with the absolute values
df["abs_c"] = df["c"].abs()
```

Step 2: sort values on absolute values of "c"

```
# sorting by absolute value of "c" & reseting the index & assigning it back to df
df = df.sort_values("abs_c",ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Step 3: get the order of column "a" based on the sorted values, this is achieved by using drop duplicates of pandas which keeps the first instance of the value in the column a which is sorted based on "c". This will be used in the next step

```
# getting the order of "a" based on sorted value of "c"
order_a = df["a"].drop_duplicates()
```

Step 4: based on the order of "a" and the sorted values of "c" creating a data frame

```
# based on the order_a creating a data frame as per the order_a which is based on the sorted values of abs "c"
sorted_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(order_a)):
  sorted_df = sorted_df.append(df[df["a"]==order_a[i]])
```

Step 5:Assigning the sorted df back to df

```
# reset index of sorted values and assigning it back to df
df = sorted_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
     a  b   c  abs_c
0   13  x  -10  10
1   13  y   0   0
2   10  x   7   7
3   10  y   0   0
4   11  x   2   2
5   11  y   0   0
```

Doc reference
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: that's not the ouput i want, it should be `10 0 7 0 2 0`

Comment: so i have re-worked the solution, to output 10 0 7 0 2 0 , hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it doesn't turn out very nice, but I almost never use panda. I hope everything works out the way you want it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [11, 11, 13, 13, 10, 10],
                   'b': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
                   'c': [2, 0, -10, 0, 7, 0]})
mask = df[df['c'] != 0]
mask['abs'] = mask['c'].abs()
mask = mask.sort_values('abs', ascending=False).reset_index()
tempNr = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['c'] != 0:
        df.loc[index] = mask.loc[tempNr].drop('abs')
        tempNr = tempNr + 1
print(df)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it prints`[(13, 'x', -10), (10, 'y', 0), (13, 'y', 0), (10, 'x', 2)]`

Comment: What exactly is your aim? Your sorted values do not match your text. My solution sorts the values according to the 3rd column. Only if the value is not 0 should it be sorted?

Comment: I have adapted my answer, because I had unfortunately overlooked that you do not want to sort the values equal to 0.

Comment: It's still not good, it doesn't sort by absolute value

Comment: thanks, could you precise how "you can simply replace the values not equal to 0 in df with the values in mask." in your answer for me to accept it ?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't turn out very nice, but I almost never use panda. I hope everything works out the way you want it.

Comment: thanks it works, i'll wait before accepting your answer to see if there is maybe a way to do it more properly with panda / numpy !